# Referencing Variables using the string from another variable

Tags: python, loops, graph, automation

I'm new to python (moving over from Eviews) and am trying to recreate a program I had in Eviews in Python. I would like to create an automated graphing program that could be easily manipulated to show 2 graphs for different states. For example, in Eviews I can define a variable at the beginning of my program by using

%state = "statename"

then refence that variable later on to create graphs in a loop like so:

```
For %x category1 category2
for %y {%state}
graph %x_%y (indicating the new graph name: category1_statename, category2_statename)
next 
next
```

It will then spit out 2 graphs, one for the first category for that state, and then another for the second category for that state. I can very quickly change the %state = "statename" to a different state and then it will spit out graphs for that new state when I run the program again. I know there has to be a way to do this in python, but I'm struggling to find it.

Any help is much appreciated!

I tried to define a variable named state at the beginning of my program, but cannot get python to recognize it when I try to reference it.

EX:

```
state = "AK"
categories = ["category1", "category2"]
for x in categories
    df.categories_value_state.plot(kind='bar')
```

error: dataframe object has no attricbute

Answer (score 0):

try `eval(variable_name)` to dynamically reference a variable or expression.